# How to get java AtomicInteger value into three digits

Tags: java, counter

I want to have a counter starting like `001` and `002`, `003` likewise. How to get it using java `AtomicInteger`? I can only get 1,2,3...

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet());
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.format("%03d", 5)` would return the string `"005"`. You can shortcut `System.out.print(String.format(pattern, values))` to just `System.out.printf(pattern, values)` (if you want the newline, toss an `\n` in your pattern string at the end).

This formatting feature works with patterns. `%` starts a pattern. `d` means: An integral number (f is for floating point numbers), `3` means: Render at least 3 characters, more if needed, and `0` means: pad it up with zeroes if you need padding because the number is less than 3 characters. Thus, `%03d` is the pattern for: Render the number, if less than 100 pad with zeroes so it's 3 digits.

Read up on the javadoc of `String.format` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As java does only store the number itself internally, you have to do that yourself.
But this is quite easily done with [`java.lang.String.format(String,Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) or `System.out.printf` like this:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
System.out.printf("%03d\n", counter.incrementAndGet());
counter.set(50);
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", counter.incrementAndGet()));
counter.set(100);
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", counter.incrementAndGet()));
```

Output:

```
001
051
101
```

Answer (score 0):

It behaves that way because that's the the AtomicInteger's method toString() returns. If you want zeroes, just make your own method for it. Remember they are now strings.